# How to toggle button icon when a bootstrap dropdown is open

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, dropdown

I have a bootstrap dropdown list and I want to change the icon displayed(*icon-deafult*) in the button when I open the drop down(to *icon-active*). Here is the code:

```
<div id="Menu" class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn btn-default" id="MyButton" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
    <i class="icon-default"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>

.icon-default {
  content: url("path/path/cool.svg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.icon-active {
  content: url("path/path/hot.svg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I tried using `.open > .icon-default {...}` but it did not work. Am I doing it right? Is there a way to do this without writing any new scripts. Can I use existing CSS or bootstrap functionality to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dropdown get the class `open` when you open it, then you should just update your selector:

```
.open .icon-default {
  content: url("path/path/hot.svg");
}
```

Comment: Yeah it does get the `open` class. and your `.open .icon-default` worked! Thanks. I am quite new to css so can you tell me why `.open > .icon-default` didn't work for me? is `>` not necessary?

Comment: The `>` selector will match `.icon-default` which is direct child of  .`open` element. The direct child of your dropdown is the `a` element, not the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses `area-expended` attribute so you can use `[aria-expanded="false"]` for closed dropdown and `[aria-expanded="true"]` for opened dropdown like this.

```
// When dropdown is closed
.dropdown > [aria-expanded="false"] > .icon-default {
    content: url("path/path/cool.svg");
}

// when dropdown is opened
.dropdown > [aria-expanded="true"] > .icon-default {
    content: url("path/path/hot.svg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
#navbarDropdownMenuLink[aria-expanded="true"]:after{
  content: url("path/path/hot.svg");
}

#navbarDropdownMenuLink[aria-expanded="false"]:after{
  content: url("path/path/cold.svg");
}
```